# Remove objects from array based on conditions in Mule 3

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-component

I want to remove the objects from the list whose profile is **Aftersales_Manager** and **raflag** is false but I'm facing and issue in DataWeave 1.0 in Mule 3. Please suggest the correct DataWeave code in Mule 3.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload filter ($.raflag != false and $.mule_temp_profile ='Aftersales_Manager') 
        map {
        "ldap": $.ldap,
        "status": $.status,
        "m_value": $.m_value,
        "raflag": $.raflag,
        "profile": $.profile
        }
```

Input:

```
[{
    "ldap": "V00075",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
}, {
    "ldap": "V00076",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
}, {
    "ldap": "V00077",
    "raflag": false,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
}, {
    "ldap": "V00078",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Worker"
}, {
    "ldap": "V00079",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Manager"
}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
    "ldap": "V00075",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
},
{
    "ldap": "V00076",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
},
{
    "ldap": "V00078",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Worker"
},
{
    "ldap": "V00079",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Manager"
}
]
```

Comment: The expected output seems incorrect if you expect `profile` to be `"Aftersales_Manager"` only. Also you should provide details on the issue you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input doesn't has a `mule_temp_profile`. I suspect you meant `profile`. And there is no need to compare `raflag` to false because it is already a boolean. The map is also unneeded, since you are outputting the same key-values after all.

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload filter ($.raflag or $.profile !='Aftersales_Manager')
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "ldap": "V00075",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
  },
  {
    "ldap": "V00076",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Aftersales_Manager"
  },
  {
    "ldap": "V00078",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Worker"
  },
  {
    "ldap": "V00079",
    "raflag": true,
    "profile": "Manager"
  }
]
```

Comment: I want keep other profile like worker and manager. Only for profile aftersales_manager if the raflag is false then that record should remove.

Comment: I updated the condition now to produce the same expected output as in the question.